# Can not get GCM registration id in emulator but result=OK as success message in emulator by phonegap

Tags: push-notification

I am building a app for android by phonegap 3.5 which have very simple features and pushnotification for android.When it run emulator then it give :

Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gsf (has extras) } U=0: not found but it give

file:///android_asset/www/js/pushnotification.js: Line 27 : result = OK. Please Help and Thank you in advance.

Comment: Bump - I'm having the same issue. Figure anything out yet @Anupam Chowdhury?

Comment: any solution same problem with me.

Comment: same problem.. any news?